# PyMySql Changing date ranges in SQL query

Tags: python, pymysql

I want to look at data for the past 7 days, so have generated the values:

```
from_date = str(date.today() - timedelta(7))
to_date = str(date.today()
```

This is so I can do a query using PyMySql such as:

```
data = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > 'from_date' AND date < 'to_date'"""
db_conn = pymysql.connect(host=xxx, user=xxx, password=xxx)
df = pd.read_sql(data, con=db_conn)
```

This doesn't work, and I've tried different quotation marks around from_date and to_date to try and do this. What is the best way to refer to this in PyMySql?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass variable values into the query through the [query parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
data = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > %s AND date < %s"""
df = pd.read_sql(data, con=db_conn, params=[from_date, to_date])
```

Here `%s` in the query are positional placeholders.

You might also need to format the dates:

```
df = pd.read_sql(data, con=db_conn, 
                 params=[from_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
                         to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')])
```

Comment: I meant to mention trying this way as well. This still pulls data from months ago doing this.